# nvd3 multibar chart shows no data

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I am trying to make my first nvd3 graph.

```
var sample_data = [{
  "key": "Stream1",
  "values": [{
    "x": "A",
    "y": 10
  }, {
    "x": "B",
    "y": 4
  }]
}, {
  "key": "Stream2",
  "values": [{
    "x": "A",
    "y": 12
  }, {
    "x": "B",
    "y": 10
  }]
}]

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
    .stacked(true)
    .showControls(false)
    .showLegend(false)
    .width(300);


  chart.multibar.stacked(true); // default to stacked
  chart.showControls(false); // don't show controls

  d3.select('#chart1 svg')
    .datum(sample_data)
    .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
});
```

For some reason, the graph shows "No Data available". But it works in this js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9xjo8yh/2/

Any ideas what may I be doing wrong?